# how to know if my video card supports OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, genymotion, video-card

the error of Genymotion when i start the API23-6.0.0

```
Unable to start virtual device
to start virtual devices, make sure your video card supports OpenGL 2.0
and update the driver
```

so, how to know if my video card supports OpenGL ES 2.0 and if there , how to update it ? i have a video card "gfx_win8_8.1_64_15.33.19.3540"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think gfx_win8_8.1_64_15.33.19.3540 is name of grafic driver.

To check **graphics card type** (Windows):

- Open the Windows Run dialog box (Click Start > Run).
- Type **dxdiag** to access a diagnostic tool that lists the graphics card information.

To determine the **OpenGL** **version** install the **OpenGL Extensions Viewer**.